# Calculate sum of working hours in sql server and display in each row regarding the EmpID

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate **SumofWorkingHours** as below which is based in empID. e.g. if EmpID is 1 then it sum the working hours in every Admincode and display sum in all rows where EmpID exist. 
Please give suggestion or query regarding this.

```
LoginName   EmpID      Practice      AdminCode     WorkingHours  SumofWorkingHours
E1          1          Admin         IT            5.24          38.81 
E1          1          Admin         Finance       0.07          38.81 
E1          1          Admin         HR           33.50          38.81 
E2          2          Admin         Support       8.00          40.50
E2          2          Admin         HR           32.50          40.50
E3          3          Admin         Finance       5.50          45.08 
E3          3          Admin         Support      39.58          45.08
```

This data is only for testing

Comment: Use "group by EmpID". select "Emp1, sum(WorkingHours)". Join with your table on Emp1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just want to sum over EmpId, like this:

```
select EmpId, sum(WorkingHours)
from theTable
group by EmpId
```

To integrate that into a larger query to specifically return the result set that you show in your question, you could do something like:

```
select t1.LoginName, t1.EmpID, t1.Practice, 
    t1.AdminCode, t1.WorkingHours, tot.SumofWorkingHours
from theTable t1
inner join (select EmpID, sum(WorkingHours) as SumofWorkingHours
            from theTable
            group by EmpId) tot 
on tot.EmpID = t1.EmpID
```

Comment: I tried the above query but nothing was happened. Actually I want to calculate sum of working hours and display column like the above example. sum of one working hour of one employee display when the empid exist in next row.

Comment: @Dinesh: What do you mean, 'nothing happened'? Did you get an error? Did you use the right tablename?

Comment: Means it display same working hours like 5.24, 0.07, 33.50, 8.00, 32.50, 5.50, 39.58 . It does not sum the working hours. I want to display the data in above format workinghours and sumofworkinghours and sumofworkinghour should display on every row regarding the EmpID.

Comment: @Dinesh: I don't know why it isn't working for you. It looks right to me.

Comment: I have tried it again and its working. Thank you Thank you very much.